# gcc, arm, inline assembly, BX produce unexpected results trying to jump over a goto section

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, cortex-m

I am using Cortex M0+;

I am trying to preserve a piece of code inside the regular code flow, don't ask me why :)
Basically later on, I'd like to jump to MYCODE.

This is the code

```
    bool x = false; // defined somewhere globally 

    if (x) goto MYCODE; // prevents removal of MYCODE

    //goto MYJUMP; // this is working as expected
    __asm volatile("BX %0" : : "r" (&&MYJUMP) : ); // this crashes !!!

MYCODE:

    __asm volatile ("nop");
    __asm volatile ("nop");
    __asm volatile ("nop");

MYJUMP:
    __asm volatile ("nop"); // first NOP will crash !!!
    __asm volatile ("nop");
    __asm volatile ("nop");
```

Now in the first place, GCC removes anything from MYCODE, no matter -Ox I use.
One way to convince to keep the code, was to declare 'x' as global and make a fake if() before.

Another way was to use jump in assembly with this

```
__asm volatile("BX %0" : : "r" (&&MYJUMP) : );
```

The generated code is

```
 96           __asm volatile("BX %0" : : "r" (&&MYJUMP) : );
0800285e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #96]  
08002860:   bx      r3                    // value is 0800286c
```

Using inline jump, always crashes into DefaultHandler!
This is very curious, the NOPs appears to be fine

```
08002864:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
100         __asm volatile ("nop");
08002866:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
101         __asm volatile ("nop");
08002868:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
102         __asm volatile ("nop");
0800286a:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
105         __asm volatile ("nop");
0800286c:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)       // <-- the code reaches here just fine as expected
106         __asm volatile ("nop");      // but when executed this NOP will jump to DefaultHandler
0800286e:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
107         __asm volatile ("nop");
08002870:   nop     ; (mov r8, r8)
```

Any idea what's happening?
I am debugging for few hours and I just don't get it.

I'd like to use assembly jump, in this case, GCC will not optimize anymore.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your code seems to be thumb but the jump is arm (LSB zero).

Comment: There are special rules for jumping out of an inline asm, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels.  You have to use `__asm goto` and specifically declare all labels that may be jumped to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jumping out of an inline asm needs special handling.  There is extra syntax for it: [`asm goto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels).

Briefly, your jump should look like this:

```
__asm goto("B %l0" : : : : MYJUMP);
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/McnWG49s1)

This compiles to a simple `b label`.  I didn't test it but the generated asm looks "obviously correct".

As a bonus you do not need to load the label address into a scratch register.  It also prevents optimizing out `MYCODE` (without the need for a dummy variable) because the compiler assumes that the jump may or may not be taken.  (The docs mention that if you want to inform the compiler that the asm will *always* jump, you can follow it with `__builtin_unreachable()`.)

Comment: Error: ARM register expected -- `bx .L17'

Comment: @orfruit: Oh right, because it's now a direct jump and needn't be interworking.  So change `bx` to a simple `b`.  Updated the answer.

Comment: I figured out myself :)) while you re-post based on you solution. Big THANK YOU !!! (also for @Jester). Works perfect!